# .net regex for all nonvisible, nonalphanumeric characters except spaces

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I have to process a string that could include all sorts of non-standard characters and I've been asked to provide a regular expression that will match and remove all characters that are non-alphanumeric except punctuation and spaces.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You mean like accented characters?

Comment: @Jack depends on his definition of "alphanumeric". I had a look into the German Wikipedia and it says "any letter and any digit", hence my answer, but the [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphanumeric) says "is used to describe the collection of **Latin letters** and Arabic digits".

Comment: Are you sure that you don't actually want to *replace the non-standard characters with their closest ASCII equivalent*? To turn someone's name, like `Èponine`, into just `ponine`, seems a bit impolite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop):

`\p{P}` or `\p{Punctuation}`: any kind of punctuation character.

`\p{L}` or `\p{Letter}`: any kind of letter from any language.

`\p{Nd}` or `\p{Decimal_Digit_Number}`: a digit zero through nine in any script except ideographic scripts.

Your regex would then look like this

```
[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{P} ]+
```

This would match anything that is not a letter, not a digit, not punctuation and not a space.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern: `@"[^\s\w]| "`
`^` symbol in squared braces means negate. So this will match everything except word characters (numbers, letters and underline) and whitespaces (`[^\s\w]`) OR a space.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regular expression.

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9!.,'" ]
```

Add any other allowed punctuation characters to the expression. The last empty space is a `space` character.

Use `\w` if underscore is allowed. `\s` would allow whitespace characters.